# Bash - extract url using find

Tags: bash, shell

When I run the following command in a directory of an extracted (inflated) XLSX, I get the all URLs found within the sub-folder files.

find . -exec exiftool {} \; | grep http

Now I want to run this as part of a bash script I have developed but it simply doesn't show anything upon completion.

Here is the code in the script:

```
if [[ $fileName == *.xlsx ]]; then 
    #file is XML based, create new directory with file name, copy file there and extract
    echo "Creating directory\n"
    DATE=`date +%Y-%m-%d`
    mkdir "Files/$DATE-$fileName-$USER"
    cp $filePath "Files/$DATE-$fileName-$USER"
    unzip "Files/$DATE-$fileName-$USER/$fileName" -d "Files/$DATE-$fileName-$USER/"
    result="find 'Files/$DATE-$fileName-$USER/$fileName' -exec exiftool {} \; | grep http"
    printf $result
fi
```

Your support is appreciated in figuring out what's wrong here.

Comment: is it just me, or are you not executing the find command, at all?

Comment: also the `== *.xlsx` ... is this a real construct? wouldn't be better served by something like `if echo $filename | grep -E '*[.]xlsx$' ; then`

Comment: @MichaelSpeer There are multiple ways of performing this check , mine and yours are just two of them. Nonetheless, if the result is the same in this use case, it becomes a matter of preference.

Comment: @MichaelSpeer, that construct has the benefit of working in a POSIX shell, but is unnecessarily heavy in bash. Also, the regular expression in your comment is incorrect, as the `*` is supposed to represent "zero or more *of the preceding atom*".

Comment: @ghoti thank you for the correction. I prefixed my other comment wondering if it was a real construct, as opposed to a misunderstanding. I later looked through the extensive bash man-page and found it. I was simply unfamiliar with it previously, and therefore questioned it alongside the apparently non-functional find statement. Thank you both for educating me in the matter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't call the command, there is the assignment

```
result="find 'Files/$DATE-$fileName-$USER/$fileName' -exec exiftool {} \; | grep http"
```

But the command is treated as a string and never executed. Also the variables in single quotes won't expand. Instead, write

```
result="$(find "Files/$DATE-$fileName-$USER/$fileName" -exec exiftool {} \; | grep http)"
```

#### Other improvements

`echo` does not recognize `\n` by default. Replace `echo "Creating directory\n"` with `echo "Creating directory"` and add another empty `echo` for an additional newline.

`printf $result` may swallow `%` escape sequences and the parts after the first space. Quote the variable and use `%s`: `printf %s "$result"`.

Don't pass directories *and* the files inside them to `exiftool`. Either use `exiftool`'s recursive option and drop the `find` part or add `-type f` to the `find` command, such that only files are listed.

Comment: Ok....So I replaced by bit with yours but I still see no output of the find command...

Comment: @ksa_coder Did you assign any value to `$fileName`, does that value end with `.xlsx`? Can you confirm that there are any files inside `Files/$DATE-$fileName-$USER/$fileName` and at least one of them has a meta-data field containing the search string `http`?